# Was Bugs Bunny always The Animator?

Tags: fourth-wall, looney-tunes, merrie-melodies

In the frankly cinematic masterpiece that is the 1953 short film ***Duck Amuck***, the titular Daffy Duck is tortured by an unseen artist, the implied hand of god of a film/cartoon known as the animator. The hand of god turns out to be none other than Daffy's arch frenemy Bugs Bunny.

Does this imply that Bugs is always the animator/hand of god in the Loony Tunes or Merrie Melodies series? Or is Bugs the real Chuck Jones? Does this extend to any of the other films with these characters?

Comment: Video not available now

Answer (score 7):

I would highly doubt that implication.  I think the animators were just having a little fun.  After all, very little about those cartoons carries over; Bugs doesn't live in the same place every time, Porky Pig's whole personality went through a metamorphosis, Daffy Duck has been paired with Porky Pig, Bugs Bunny and Elmer Fudd.  It's an ever changing world.

[The cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Amuck), as it were, was so well-liked it was selected for preservation in the National Film Registry.  The important piece from that Wiki page that relates to your question would be:

> Although in the end, the animator is revealed to be Daffy's rival Bugs
>   Bunny (who declares "Ain't I a stinker?"), according to Jones the
>   ending is just for comedic value: Jones (the director) is speaking to
>   the audience directly, asking "Who is Daffy Duck anyway? Would you
>   recognize him if I did this to him?

Comment: Arguably, the use of Bugs is a quick short-hand. If they used some random animator, the lack of characterization probably detracts from the humor (we don't wonder about the animator's apparent sadism etc.). We presumably know Bugs more intimately.

Comment: Well, yeah.  We all know Bugs likes to torment Daffy at times.  It definitely makes sense to have Bugs be the animator, but only for that one episode.